# RestKit EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 2 on addPropertyMapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

when I`m adding relation to the`RKEntityMapping` object like this

```
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping 
               relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"user"
               withMapping:[MappingProvider userMapping]]];
```

debugger show me info

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2)" on method:  static NSArray
>   *RKEntityIdentificationAttributeNamesForEntity(NSEntityDescription *entity) in file RestKit/Core Data/RKEntityMapping.m

[See link here](http://cl.ly/image/2d1q1n3A3d3X)

My implemetation - in AppDelgate is RestKit setup:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = RKEnsureDirectoryExistsAtPath(RKApplicationDataDirectory(), &error);
if (! success) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed to create Application Data Directory at path '%@': %@", RKApplicationDataDirectory(), error);
}
NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sCookingDB.sqlite"];
NSLog(@"Setting up store at %@", path);
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path
                                                                     fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil
                                                                          withConfiguration:nil
                                                                                    options:[self optionsForSqliteStore]
                                                                                      error:&error];
if (! persistentStore) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed adding persistent store at path '%@': %@", path, error);
}
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];
```

In controller I have method

```
-(void) loadProducts {
    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping: [MappingProvider productMapping] method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern: nil keyPath: nil statusCodes:statusCodes];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/products"]];
    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

    operation.managedObjectContext = [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
    operation.managedObjectCache = [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] managedObjectCache];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
        self.products = result.array;
        NSLog(@"%@", self.products);
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Request failed"];
    }];
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Mapping [MappingProvider productMapping] is:

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[[Product class] description]
                                                   inManagedObjectStore:  [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                  @"_id": @"productId",
                                                  @"name" : @"name",
                                                  @"created": @"created",

                                                  }];
    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"productId" ];
    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                            toKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                          withMapping:[MappingProvider userMapping]]];

    return mapping;
```

When I will remove line with "`addPropertyMapping`", code works fine, but of course it`s only get products whithout user.

The model [entities](http://cl.ly/image/2c2W2m1j0j3P)

I do not know if I'm doing something wrong, whether it is a bug in RestKit.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about using ```userMapping``` instead of ```[MappingProvider userMapping]```. I can't see where the provider is informed about the mapping.

Comment: Whole mapping provider class http://cl.ly/code/1K3O0j3F3K1J
In loadProducts I have line 


"RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping: [MappingProvider productMapping] method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern: nil keyPath: nil statusCodes:statusCodes];"

 that inform provider about mapping.

Comment: Don't use `[[Product class] description]`, use `NSStringFromClass`. And does the class name match the entity name?

Comment: ok I have changed to NSStringFromClass but still is the same error. Class name match the entity. I capture that on video http://screencast.com/t/7K0ApyAIP

Answer (score 1):

You have configured your `MappingProvider` class to run in an infinite loop. The `userMapping` method calls `productMapping` which then calls `userMapping` again. Any call to either method will trigger this loop. The bad access error occurs because the device runs out of memory to allocate as the recursive loop has taken it all.

Try to rewrite your mappings so this recursive dependancy doesn't exist. Mapping one side of the relationship should be sufficient.